# Does Google recognized elements hidden behind a v-if?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I got a quick question about the v-if function: Does google still recognizes blocks that are "hidden" via v-if? We got some elements that only show if a user clicked a certain button or that changes if he does certain things but the content in those blocks would be important to the google crawler since they include important Informations about products etc but they are only there after the User made a certain interaction.

So does google still find those Informations or are they not findable for google then?

Comment: No it does not becuse `v-if` completly removes it from the DOM. Also, i guess you made an SPA app without server side rendering, therefor the site isnt good for crawlers anyway, you should consider using Nuxt.js that is build for that

Comment: If you are doing ssr and use css to hide the block instead of actually remove it from the html file. `display:hidden`. If you are not doing ssr like @Ilijanovic mentioned then you should consider do ssr first

Comment: @Ilijanovic I use nuxt js. and its not a single page application. Is there a better way to do it that woks just like v-if but doesnt ocmpletly remove them so google still can find it.?

Comment: @Erik Consider explaining your case, could be also the question for https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ because this boils down to what should be rendered to DOM. Notice that making it hidden will likely not affect SEO in a good way, it may be discarded because modern crawlers including google are supposed to take into account how it's displayed

Comment: @EstusFlask Iam building a new page that informs about a few things. First time to make the whole package alone. I built some elements that work with v-if, for example a kind of accordeon and when you click it it opens and shows the text thats saved in it. If you click it a funciton is called which sets a value to true and if the value is true the box is shown. I have used the v-if on mutlible elements and it just occured to me that it maybe not so good for google crawlers.

Comment: It's expected that dynamic content that isn't shown on the page by default is not indexed, yes. Depends on how important it is. You can hide it with v-show and hope that it will be taken into account, although it's also expected that it can be ignored because it's invisible, and also can result in a penalty. Or create a separate url with unfolded accordeon if it's important for seo

Comment: @Erik yes, you can use v-show

Answer (score 4):

No, elements that have `v-if` do not render in DOM if the condition is false.

You can use `v-show` directive instead, it will render the element but apply an inline style of `display: none` to hide it.

[Link to Vue documents](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/conditional.html#v-show)